# SharedPreferences does not save checkbox status

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

I'm developing task list application using sharedpreferences. but it doesn't save checkbox status. I want to save when user click on checkbox. After user exits the application and see again it is already updated status. How to save checkbox status? 
Here is my code (Already Fixed and Working)

```
public class TaskList extends Activity {
    CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4;
    Boolean checked = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findID();

        cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
        Log.i("start", "" + isChecked);
        cb1.setChecked(isChecked);
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("boolean", "" + isChecked);
                putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");

            }
        });
    }

    public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this
                .getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this
                .getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return isChecked;
    }

    private void findID() {
        cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand you only want to achieve this behaviour for cb1

Comment: Why is the line that saves the pref commented out and why does it reference the unknown class `Settings`?

Comment: Yes, i only want for cb1

Comment: @popovitsj Yes, I have block Settings line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the value in `SharedPreferencesevery` time `CheckBox` check status is changed.
Remove comment from this line `Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked")` in `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

So, your listener will be as below :

```
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("boolean", "" + isChecked);

                putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class TaskList extends Activity {

    private CheckBox cb1;
    private CheckBox cb2;
    private CheckBox cb3;
    private CheckBox cb4;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);

        cb1.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("cb1",false));
        cb2.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("cb2",false));
        cb3.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("cb3",false));
        cb4.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("cb4",false));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("cb1", isChecked);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
        cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("cb2", isChecked);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
        cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("cb3", isChecked);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
        cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("cb4", isChecked);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful too. you just 1 minus late to give accept answer. Thanks for your help.